# Mongodb Field constraint for minimum value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a field in mongodb and it is of integer type. I want to clip the minimum value to zero (0, it shouldn't go negative) on update action like $inc.

Any idea how to achieve this constraint? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MongoDB itself is "schemaless" it cannot really enforce any "schema logic" by itself for such a constraint.

You can possibly look into Object Document Mapper (ODM) libraries available for your chosen language, but all of these generally require that the data be "loaded into the client" in order to enforce such constraints upon modifications.

Additionally, there is no current "operator syntax" that allows such a constaint, such as for [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to not fall below ( or go above ) a certain value.

What you "can" do however is use something like the ["Bulk" operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) to send "two" requests at once, respectively doing:

- Increment/Decrement the field by the specified value
- Check if the field fell out of constraints and set the value accordingly.

So for a simple example of a Min of "0" and a Max of "100" you would do:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// Increment document field
bulk.find({ "_id": idValue }).updateOne({ 
    "$inc": { "counter": incValue }
});

// Set to Max if greater than Max
bulk.find({ "_id": idValue, "counter": { "$gt": 100 } }).updateOne({ 
    "$set": { "counter": 100 }
});

// Set to Min if less than Min
bulk.find({ "_id": idValue, "counter": { "$lt": 0 } }).updateOne({ 
    "$set": { "counter": 0 }
});

// Only sends and returns from server now
bulk.execute();
```

That means that though there are actually "three" operations here to enforce the constraint, there is actually only "one" request to the server and "one" response.

Whilst it still really is "three" operations, the likelihood of the "interim" value being picked up is very small. So this is generally preferred to loading the data from the server, then modifying and saving back the contents in all respects.

Comment: Thanks Blakes for this suggestion, this seems like a good idea :)
It seems like these 3 operations cannot be avoided for now..

Comment: @HongZhou No they cannot really be avoided doing things safely. The benefit here with "Bulk" is that it is only one request and one response, and if nothing modifies or even matches then it is not reported back either. I would not be waiting for this to change soon.

Answer (score 0):

This option is not very efficient one but may be one of the choice in your case of

```
      http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/
```

You can write a javascript function which will do the increment before validating the data. But i am still sure concurrency may have a problem that you need to consider.